# Get ContentChildren of downgraded ng2 component

Tags: angular

I have a ng1 application which has been bootstraped using upgradeAdapter and uses downgraded ng2 components.

But I faced a problem with a @ContentChildren decorator. It seems that @ContentChildren doesn't see ng2 components which has been downgraded to ng1 directives.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aAoTsTtsJgZXjX3mswcN

**ParentComponent**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><ng-content></ng-content>',
    directives: [ChildCmp]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ContentChildren(ChildCmp) members = new QueryList();

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.members); //always with length 0
  }

}
```

**ChildComponent**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-cmp',
    template: '<h2>Child</h2>'
})
export class ChildCmp { }
```

**bootstrap**:

```
var upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
angular.module('ng1App').directive('myApp', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
angular.module('ng1App').directive('childCmp', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(ChildCmp));
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document, ['ng1App']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encoutered the same problem. But there is a workaround:

Create an Angular 2 wrapper component which uses the parent and child components in it's template. In this component, you import your parent and child components and define them as directives in the @Component configuration. Then you only downgrade your wrapper component and use this one in your html.

Comment: There is also an issue in the Angular2 Git repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7933

Answer (score 0):

I have created a wrap module for resolving this problem.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [
        WrapComponent,
        ParentComponent,
        ChildComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        WrapComponent,
        ParentComponent,
        ChildComponent,
    ],
    entryComponents:[WrapComponent],
})
export class WrapModule {
    constructor(){
        console.log('WrapModule');
    }
}
```

For example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HBAPMv?p=preview)